# keyword display my website with anchor tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, keyboard

i have a site which make with php. there keywords come up with `<?php echo $settings['keywords']; ?>`

with this code `<?php echo $settings['keywords']; ?>` show all tag together. like fast keyword, 2nd keyword, third keyword

i like to display those keyword with anchor tag in my website body footer. 
like `<a href="mysite">fast keyword </a> , <a href="mysite">2nd keyword </a>`

i have search stackoverflow but but i am confused

Comment: Just put the echo where you want it to appear. Like `<a href="mysite"><?php echo ....`

Comment: What is `$settings['keywords']`? Array, or string, seperated by spaces/commas or sth. other?

Comment: this display into keywords `<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $settings['keywords']; ?>" />`
but i like to add all keywords into my site body with anchor tag

Comment: @iamsleepy if i use this `<a href="mysite"><?php echo....`
 all keyword showing tegether not with ,

Comment: Do you have separator for each keyword ? Like `,` or `:` perhaps a space ?

Comment: @iamsleepy i like to separate each keyword with `,`

Comment: @iamsleepy i want separated like `<a href="mysite">fast keyword </a> , <a href="mysite">2nd keyword </a>`
   but now display like `fast keyword, 2nd keyword`

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But, what I mean was how did you store the keywords inside the `$settings['keywords']`. Basically what was the actual output for the echo you did?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the keywords in an iterable object, you can iterate over them with a `foreach` loop. Use `explode` if it's a string that's comma-delimited:

```
<?php 
$arr_keywords = explode(",",$settings['keywords']);
foreach($arr_keywords as $keyword)
{
    if($keyword != $array_keywords[count($array_keywords)-1])
        echo "<a href=\"\">".$keyword."</a>,";
    else
        echo "<a href=\"\">".$keyword."</a>";
}
?>
```

Comment: this code given this error `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/folder/x.php on line 62`

Comment: This is because `$settings` is a string, and `foreach` expects an array. See my answer.

Comment: @Arthe That just means you need to explode it and make it iterable. I edited the answer.

Comment: @AlexW its working but `,` not showing all keyword showing like `fast keyword second keyword`
if `,` there that will be great :)

Answer (score 0):

> i want separated like ..... but now display like `fast keyword, 2nd keyword`

I suppose you have a string with words, seperated by spaces. I think you need this:

```
foreach(explode(" ", $settings['keywords']) as $keyword) {
   echo '<a href="">'.$keyword.'</a>';
}
```